# Bitmap.SetPixel(int x, int y, Color color) throws ArgumentException: Invalid Parameter

Tags: c#, xna

```
if (map[x, y] != null)
save.SetPixel(x, y, System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(map[x, y].r, map[x, y].g, map[x, y].b));
```

This code is part of a function where x and y are ints.
save is a Bitmap.

```
save = CreateNonIndexedImage(Bitmap.FromFile("Content/save/map.png"));
```

map[,] is an array consisting of Tile, which is a class of mine. Tile.r, Tile.g and Tile.b are ints.

Why is this throwing a ArgumentException?

The StackTrace:

```
   bei System.Drawing.Image.get_Width()
   bei System.Drawing.Bitmap.SetPixel(Int32 x, Int32 y, Color color)
   bei RogueLike.Game1.saveTile(Int32 x, Int32 y) in C:\Users\Niklas\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\RogueLike\RogueLike\RogueLike\Game1.cs:Zeile 472.
```

Comment: Sorry, I know this is an old question but do you think it could have something to do with the pixel format? (e.g. it expects an 8 bit color but is getting a 24 bit one?)

Answer (score 2):

According to MSDN, `Bitmap.SetPixel` does not throw the ArgumentException, however `Color.FromArgb` does when

> red, green, or blue is less than 0 or greater than 255.

Therefore one of `map[x, y].r`, `map[x, y].g` or `map[x, y].b` is outside of the integer interval `[0..255]`.

Comment: map[x, y].r = 0 map[x, y].g=255 map[x, y].b=0

Comment: @user3258697, that's strange. Which of these methods, precisely, is throwing the exception?

Comment: Here´s the Stacktrace:    bei System.Drawing.Image.get_Width()
   bei System.Drawing.Bitmap.SetPixel(Int32 x, Int32 y, Color color)
   bei RogueLike.Game1.saveTile(Int32 x, Int32 y) in C:\Users\Niklas\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\RogueLike\RogueLike\RogueLike\Game1.cs:Zeile 472.

Comment: @user3258697, better update the post with it - will be more readable

Comment: @user3258697, from the stack trace it looks like `x` is greater than the image width. Have you verified it is correct?

Comment: I ust found my mistake. It seems like the first call worked but when I call it again it will crash. I just deleted my Bitmap.Dispose() :D

Comment: @Hobbit9797, I guess it would be a good idea to update the question with relevant code, post the solution and mark it as answer. Might help others running into similar issue

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your image is smaller than your data, causing out of range exceptions in your SetPixel function call.

Comment: Both, my array and my Bitmap have a size of 800x600.